# Find the shortest path of a directed non-negative weighted graph avoiding any vertices of a given subset vertices to be next to each other?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Suppose I am given a simple directed non-negative weighted graph G = (V, E) and a subset of vertices X ⊂ V. The graph is in adjacency list representation and the subset X as a list.
How do I find an algorithm that computes a shorted path between vertice s,t in the graph that doesn't belong to X, and that whenever the path uses two vertices in X, there's at least a vertice that's not in X between these two vertices? The algorithm should be in O(m+nlogn) time.

I have been thinking about this for a long time but couldn't find an algorithm that's under O(m+nlogn) time, any idea how I can approach this?

Comment: What about deleting from the graph edges between pairs of vertices in X? Then just run Dijkstra's on the new graph.

Comment: Oh hold on, you may be right. But would that be in O(m+nlongn)time?

Comment: Assuming `m = |E|` and `n = |V|`, Dijkstra's with a Fibonacci heap runs in `O(m + n log n)`. If querying whether a vertex is in X can be done in constant time, then removing the edges would just be another `O(m)`. So yes, the whole thing satisfies your time complexity requirement. If the query isn't `O(1)` (because X is a linked-list for example), then you can first make it so by building a hashset of X in `O(n)`. That doesn't increase the total complexity either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `m = |E|` and `n = |V|`.

Dijkstra's algorithm with a Fibonacci heap runs in `O(m + n log n)`. So you want to consider the extra constraint without increasing the final time complexity.

If querying whether a vertex is in X cannot be done in constant time, then you first need to make it so by building a hashset of X in `O(n)`. The subsequent queries using this hashset will run in constant time.

Now, removing from the graph the edges between pairs of vertices in X just adds another `O(m)`. Then, you can run Dijkstra's on this new graph with the edges removed, and the whole thing only takes `O(m + n log n)` time.

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand now!